# "Could not normalize path for file" when running gradle check

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I get this error when I attempt to run `gradle check` on my android project in android studio. `gradle assemble` works succesfuly. I've seen solutions to this problem to check "use external build", but with my version of android studio (0.3.7), us should do this automatically. My code should be correct, because this built on a different machine (a mac), but will not compile on my windows box. Something to do with my environment. Any ideas?

```
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':VirtualWalk:testDebug'.
> Could not normalize path for file 'D:\android-sdk\platforms\android-14\android.jar;D:\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar'.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':VirtualWalk:testDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:283)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:214)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:276)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:78)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not normalize path for file 'D:\android-sdk\platforms\android-14\android.jar;D:\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.normalise(AbstractFileResolver.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.resolve(AbstractFileResolver.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.resolve(AbstractFileResolver.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileCollectionConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileCollections(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileCollectionConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:157)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileCollections(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileCollectionConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:157)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileCollections(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:144)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getFiles(CompositeFileCollection.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.util.GUtil.addToCollection(GUtil.java:135)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.WorkerProcessBuilder.applicationClasspath(WorkerProcessBuilder.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.ForkingTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(ForkingTestClassProcessor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:132)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.normalise(AbstractFileResolver.java:94)
    ... 25 more
```

EDIT: Attached build script below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        classpath 'com.squareup.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(':submodules:java:virtual-walk-includes'))
    compile(project(':submodules:android:numberpicker'))
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto-parent:1.3.4'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.2.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.1'
    testCompile 'org.easymock:easymock:3.2'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.4'
    testCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'
}
```

EDIT: The only 2 other build files in my project:
One:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'

}
```

Two:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Eventually did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I switched back to a mac...

Comment: Do you have any another solution?

Comment: @JohnnyZ This was a bug in the Android Gradle plugin that is now fixed in v1.1.2 - see my updated answer for the fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your Android Gradle plugin version to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
}
```

This was a bug in earlier versions of the plugin that didn't properly escape illegal characters on Windows, and its fixed in v1.1.2:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=148912

Comment: Thanks. Mine was still classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, the following is not a valid Windows file path (it looks more like a class path):

```
'D:\android-sdk\platforms\android-14\android.jar;D:\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar'
```

Chances are this is caused by a (syntax?) error somewhere in the build script.

Comment: I don't. Since this is a multi-project build, perhaps the problem is in one of the other build scripts.

Comment: There are only two other projects, so posted the build.gradle files for those as well.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the Square plugin for robolectric. Looking into it, it does the same thing we do which is pass this to the bootClasspath property of the CompileOptions associated with the java compile task, but it doesn't seem to be what we used it for (comment about only being useful for when forking is set to true. I think we should set those jar files on the classpath instead. Peter can you confirm?

Comment: @Xavier Confirm what? I don't have enough context to follow what you are saying.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I'm confused about the use of CompileOptions.bootClasspath. The string value above (containing the two paths) is passed to bootClasspath. I'm not sure this is the right thing to do.

Comment: Setting the compiler's bootstrap class path is rarely needed, but I don't know your exact requirements. Looking at the exception, I don't understand how the compiler's bootstrap class path would affect test execution (this is where it blows up).